# Error loading shared library libsqlite3.so.0 in Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, docker

I'm getting the following stack trace when I try to build a Rails application in a Docker container from Alpine Ruby 2.6.3.

I've tried installing `sqlite`, `sqlite-dev`, and `sqlite-libs`, since there is no `apk` package for "libsqlite3".

Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
LoadError: Error loading shared library libsqlite3.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so) - /usr/local/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.4-alpine3.9

WORKDIR /app

ENV RAILS_ENV=production
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true

EXPOSE 3000


####
# Setup ruby environment
####

COPY ./admin/Gemfile* ./admin/*.gemspec ./admin/
COPY ./admin/lib/admin/version.rb ./admin/lib/admin/

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual=.build-deps \
  git openssh-client build-base mariadb-dev sqlite-libs sqlite-dev sqlite \
#Installing bundler without versioning could break things.
  && gem install bundler --pre \
  && bundle install --without=development,test \
  && bundle config \
  && apk del .build-deps

COPY . ./

RUN bundle config && bundle \
  && rm -f config/database.yml \
  && DATABASE_URL=sqlite3:/tmp/assets_dummy.sqlite3 bundle exec rake assets:precompile

COPY entrypoint /usr/local/bin/entrypoint
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic libraries or shared objects (files ending in `.so`) need to be present on the system in order to run the program.  Your long `RUN` command is installing `sqlite-libs` and using it during the `bundle install` phase, but then deleting it again; the `sqlite` gem needs the dynamic library to still be installed.

I'd install this in a separate `RUN` command.  Since the development package is likely to depend on the runtime library, I'd install it first to reduce churn and download time (marginally).

```sh
RUN apk add --no-cache sqlite-libs
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual=.build-deps \
  git openssh-client build-base mariadb-dev sqlite-dev \
  ... \
  && apk del .build-deps
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked!